# Apply Css on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, webix

I am using below CSS to apply `Active` and `Inactive` CSS to two buttons.

On page load one button will be "active" and the other button "InActive".

```
.buttonactive button  {
    color: white;
    font: bold;
    /*background: chocolate;*/
    background-color:#39373e;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.buttonInactive button{
    color: white;font: bold;
    background-color:#adaaaf;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

using the below code on page load

```
//set CSS

webix.html.addCss($$("btnApps").getNode(), "buttonactive");
webix.html.addCss($$("btnTitles").getNode(), "buttonInactive");
```

Up to here CSS are applying correctly.

When I click on the second button the `active` CSS class should apply and the other button should apply the `inactive` CSS class. However, it is not working for me?

```
{view: "button", id:"btnApps", value: "Apps", width: 205, height: 35, click: "getApps();" },

{ view: "button", id:"btnTitles", value: "Titles", width: 205, height: 35, click: "getTitles();" },

function getApps() {
webix.html.addCss($$("btnTitles").getNode(), "buttonInactive");
webix.html.addCss($$("btnApps").getNode(), "buttonactive");
}

function getTitles() {
webix.html.addCss($$("btnTitles").getNode(), "buttonactive");
webix.html.addCss($$("btnApps").getNode(), "buttonInactive");
}
```

Here is the snippet code

https://snippet.webix.com/k9oj9wpu

Comment: It doesn't look like you're ever removing the Css class using something like `webix.html.removeCss($$("btnTitles"), "buttonactive");` So potentially both classes are on the element in question.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for the click handler is wrong. you should use this syntax:

click: getApps

As specified in the doc here: [webix button click](https://docs.webix.com/api__ui.button_click_config.html)

Your snippet code corrected with the right syntax is here:

https://snippet.webix.com/dx5d9e49